# what is the correct way of renaming your xaml file?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

i am renaming my MainPage.xaml file and trying to make some other page as MainPage.xaml, for which i simply renamed it from xaml (x:Class) and then .cs file.

so while running my project now i am getting a XamlParseException on this line from the generated file(MainPage.g.i.cs)

System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/XYZ;component/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));

so any clue on what went wrong?...

Comment: so classes are renamed, files are renamed, correct? have you renamed also old files?

Comment: try creating a test project with two pages and then run it once, after that interchange their names, u'll face exactly what i am facing..

Answer (score 0):

The filenames are only important to navigation, such as the initial start-up page from the WMAppManifest.xml.

For `x:Class` you specify the **class name**, not the filename, ie.:

```
public class HelloWorld : PhoneApplicationFrame
```

Here **HelloWorld** is the **class name**, and should match in `x:Class` , of course with the corresponding namespace (if any).